# How do I bounce, move, and jump a sprite simultaneously in AndEngine

Tags: android, android-layout, box2d, andengine

I am looking to move a sprite in the same manner as in [this video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f433futdgy11oxs/expectations.wmv).  I am using AndEngine. How do I move that ninja(sprite), complete with move and jump, using the AndEngine Box2D physics extension.

Here is my MainActivity1.class:

```
public class MainActivity1 extends BaseGameActivity {

    Scene scene;
    private TiledTextureRegion mPlayerTextureRegion;
    private BoundCamera mBoundChaseCamera;
    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 1024;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 600;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlasp;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlashm;
    private TextureRegion mhomeTextureRegion;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas1;
    AnimatedSprite player;
    private Body playerBody;
    private PhysicsWorld mPhysicsWorld;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas sheetBitmapTextureAtlas1;
    private BitmapTextureAtlas sheetBitmapTextureAtlasplaybtn1;
    private TiledTextureRegion mTargetTextureRegionplaybtn1;


    public void onLoadComplete() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public Engine onLoadEngine() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int cameraWidth = display.getWidth();
        int cameraHeight = display.getHeight();
    //      Toast.makeText(this, "The tile the player is walking on will be highlighted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        this.mBoundChaseCamera = new BoundCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
        return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new RatioResolutionPolicy(cameraWidth, cameraHeight), this.mBoundChaseCamera));
    }

    public void onLoadResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512,
                TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);

        mBitmapTextureAtlas1 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024,
                TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
        this.sheetBitmapTextureAtlasplaybtn1 = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512);
        mTargetTextureRegionplaybtn1 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createTiledFromAsset(sheetBitmapTextureAtlasplaybtn1, this,
                        "gfx/gameplay_stormstrike_full.png",  0, 212,1, 1);
    this.mBitmapTextureAtlasp = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
        this.mPlayerTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlasp, this, "gfx/storm_strike.png", 0, 0, 1, 1); // 72x128


        mTargetTextureRegion1 = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
                .createTiledFromAsset(sheetBitmapTextureAtlas1, this,
                        "gfx/kolobok_04_walk.png",  0, 212,12, 1);

        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.sheetBitmapTextureAtlas);
        this.mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(this.sheetBitmapTextureAtlas1);
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlashm, this, "gfx/loading_ipad.png", 0, 0);
        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mBitmapTextureAtlas);
        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(sheetBitmapTextureAtlasplaybtn1);

        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mBitmapTextureAtlasp);
        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mBitmapTextureAtlas1);
        mEngine.getTextureManager().loadTexture(mBitmapTextureAtlashm);

    }

    public Scene onLoadScene() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new ColorBackground(0, 0, 0.8784f));


        this.mPhysicsWorld = new FixedStepPhysicsWorld(30, new Vector2(0, 0), false, 8, 1);
        final Sprite help = new Sprite(50, 70, mProjectileTextureRegionhelp);
        scene.attachChild(help);
        help.setVisible(false);




        player = new AnimatedSprite(100, 200, 150,150,this.mPlayerTextureRegion)
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                    case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


                     playerBody.setLinearVelocity(10f,-10f);


                        break;
                    case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:




                        break;
                    case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:

                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        scene.attachChild(player);
        scene.registerTouchArea(player);
        projectilesToBeAdded.add(player);





        AnimatedSprite playerbtn = new AnimatedSprite(10, 200, this.mTargetTextureRegionplaybtn1)
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
                    case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        playerBody.applyForce(new Vector2(200,-1500), new Vector2(playerBody.getWorldCenter()));






                        break;
                    case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:



                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
        scene.attachChild(playerbtn);
        scene.registerTouchArea(playerbtn);


        final FixtureDef carFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(10.0f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        this.playerBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(this.mPhysicsWorld, this.player, BodyType.DynamicBody, carFixtureDef);

        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(this.player, this.playerBody, true,false));






        scene.setTouchAreaBindingEnabled(true);

        this.scene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);


        return scene;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you limited the provided code to the relevant excerpt.  For example, the onLoadComplete(), onLoadEngine(), onLoadResources() sections are irrelevant to your question.  Focusing it down will help you get more responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The movement taking place in the sample video involves several different concepts.  You should be reading through the AndEngine Examples.  In particular, take a look at these two:

- org.andengine.examples.PhysicsExample
- org.andengine.examples.PhysicsJumpExample

To start the jump you're going to want to call applyForce() on the physics body of the ninja.    You'll need friction on the ninja and the surface he's bouncing against to produce the bounce.  Per the comments below, I'm going to provide some additional definitions.  Incidentally, these didn't come from me, they're from [the manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html).

### Density

> The fixture density is used to compute the mass properties of the
>   parent body. The density can be zero or positive. You should generally
>   use similar densities for all your fixtures. This will improve
>   stacking stability.  The mass of a body is not adjusted when you set
>   the density. You must call ResetMassData for this to occur.

### Velocity

> In kinematics, velocity is the rate of change of the position of an
>   object, equivalent to a specification of its speed and direction of
>   motion. Speed describes only how fast an object is moving, whereas
>   velocity gives both how fast and in what direction the object is
>   moving.

### Friction

> Friction is used to make objects slide along each other realistically.
>   Box2D supports static and dynamic friction, but uses the same
>   parameter for both. Friction is simulated accurately in Box2D and the
>   friction strength is proportional to the normal force (this is called
>   Coulomb friction). The friction parameter is usually set between 0 and
>   1, but can be any non-negative value. A friction value of 0 turns off
>   friction and a value of 1 makes the friction strong. When the friction
>   force is computed between two shapes, Box2D must combine the friction
>   parameters of the two parent fixtures. This is done with the geometric
>   mean:

```
float32 friction;

friction = sqrtf(shape1->friction * shape2->friction);
```

> So if one fixture has zero friction then the contact will have zero
>   friction.

Comment: thnkyou.i did get difference between applying force,apply linear velocity to body.any way i ll try to solve.

Comment: @radha added the definitions you requested.

Comment: thankyou somuch.i think u saw my vedio.for moving that background tilmap is ok?

Comment: @radha Tilemap might even be overkill for that background.  If you just want that, I'd take a look at the AndEngine autoparallax example, here:  http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/AutoParallaxBackgroundExample.java

Comment: autoparlex means same background i can replace.but i want move no of backround.if alredy moved background i dont want to repeat.

Comment: @radha I don't understand what you just said, sorry.

Comment: plese observer my vedio.autoparlex means same background we ll repeat always.but in my app i want move backround like autoparlex,but not to repeate same backround,always user wants to feel its new backround.

Comment: @radha I've seen the video.  Cool stuff.  A background is just a sprite.  If you want it to have various layers that move at different speeds, that's called parallax.  If you want it generated from an xml file, you'll likely use the TMX plugin.

Comment: yes. sory for asking so much  doubts,becz am new to andengine. but i phone some one did  that app already. so i have different  backround images those all i want to move.how to use xml i saw in andengine examples texturepacker example.thts working if i replce another image  in same  example,i am getting balack screen

Comment: @radha, try splitting the problem into two steps.  First get a sprite rendering normally (i.e., without texturepacker).  Once you've got it working, try implementing texturepacker.  Incidentally, we've moved way past the original topic.  Can I persuade you to checkmark my answer (to the left of the votes), assuming it helped you?

Comment: ur suggestions is good.but i wants to leran more.i tried jumping using applied force but i didnt get u have time pls solve that issue.